# Transformation of function of three random variables

Tags: probability, integration, convolution

I have been doing exercises in basic probabilities, and there is a type of questions which I am never quite sure of the answer, so I wanted to get some opinion about the way I do it.

The question is the following:
Consider $W = XY - Z$, where $\{X,Y,Z\}$ follows a Normal $(\mu,\Sigma)$ and I want to get $\Pr(W>0)$.

In the case where $W$ would be a transformation of two variables it's not that hard to figure out what the domain of integration on a plane is, but here can I proceed in the following way?
$$
\Pr(W>0\mid X=x) =  \Pr(Z<XY\mid X=x) \\
            =   \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \int_\infty^{xy} \frac{\phi(x,y,z)}{\phi_X(x)} \, dz \, dy
$$
And then use the law of total probability to get:
$$
\Pr(W>0) = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \Pr(W>0\mid X=x) \phi_X(x) \, dx
$$

Thank you

Comment: Looks good, since $f_{Z|X,Y}(z|x,y)= \frac{f_{XYZ}(x,y,z)}{f_{XY}(x,y)}$.

Comment: In the general case the formula will be awfully complicated (and I do not see how the manipulations in your question can help). Sure there are no restriction on $\mu$ and $\Sigma$?